# HTML dataset - how to put object? data-x={}

Tags: javascript, html

### HTML:

```html
<a data-test="{a: 1}">test</a>
```

But in Chrome `Console`:

```sh
> document.querySelector('a').dataset.test
< "{a: 1}"

typeof document.querySelector('a').dataset.test
"string"
```

I expected:

```sh
> document.querySelector('a').dataset.test
< {a: 1}

typeof document.querySelector('a').dataset.test
"object"
```

How can I write this HTML?
(Without javascript)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have removed the Chinese text from the question because this is an [English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3082296).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your HTML as the following.

```html
<a data-test='{"a": 1}'>test</a>
```

And then in your script

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(document.querySelector('a').dataset.test));
```

The output will be

```
{a: 1}
```

Comment: This is [an English-only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/3082296). Please do not post answers in Chinese

Comment: @adiga Alright sure. Just thought the person who ask this question is probably fluent in Mandarin so I'll post an answer in Mandarin. For your information I do both languages. As a side note the answer is pretty self explanatory as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

You just can use `JSON.parse(string object)`.

```
var x = JSON.parse(document.querySelector('a').dataset.test);

console.log(x);
```

Editted:
Please make sure that your object attribute in your `<a>` tag is a valid JSON. It should be `<a data-test='{"a": 1}'>test</a>`

Comment: Note that the string in the example is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. A dataset item of an element can *only* contain a string, nothing else - after all, it's meant to be *representable directly in the HTML*, and the HTML is a string.

Either set the dataset item in JSON format and parse it later:

```
<a data-test='{"a": 1}'>test</a>
```

(note the double quotes around the key, as required by JSON)

```js
const a = document.querySelector('a');
a.dataset.test = JSON.stringify({ a: 1 });

const test = JSON.parse(a.dataset.test);
console.log(test);
console.log(typeof test);
```

```html
<a>test</a>
```

Or associate the element with its data some other way, perhaps with a Map whose keys are the elements, and values are the associated objects (if that's an option):

```js
const map = new Map();
const a = document.querySelector('a');
map.set(a, { a: 1 });

const result = map.get(a);
console.log(result);
console.log(typeof result);
```

```html
<a>test</a>
```